# Visual C++: Compiler Error C4430

Tags: c++, visual-c++, syntax-error

The code of **Game.h**:

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

class Game
{
    public:
        const static string QUIT_GAME; // line 8
        virtual void playGame() = 0;
};

#endif
```

The error:

```
game.h(8): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
game.h(8): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'QUIT_GAME'
game.h(8): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what you need to fix your issues:

**1. Include the string header file:**
`#include <string>`

**2. Prefix `string` with its namespace:**
`const static std::string QUIT_GAME;`

or insert a `using` statement:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
```

**3.  Allocate space for the variable**
Since you declared it as `static` within the class, it must be *defined* somewhere in the code:
`const std::string Game::QUIT_GAME;`

**4. Initialize the variable with a value**
Since you declared the string with `const`, you will need to initialize it to a value (or it will remain a constant empty string).:
`const std::string Game::QUIT_GAME = "Do you want to quit?\n";`

Comment: Don't use `using` in header files. Very bad juju. Otherwise, great, comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 8):

You need to do two things:

- `#include <string>`
- Change the type to `const static std::string QUIT_GAME` (adding `std::`)

Comment: Actually one more thing:  initialize the variable.  The `const` specifier is the kicker here.  If the variable is not initialized, it will be a constant empty string.  This has uses, but I don't think it is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Note that you cannot initialize a string (even a constant static string) inside the class declaration. There must be a separate definition statement (of the form `const std::string Game::QUIT_GAME = "Whatever";`) inside the corresponding source (.cpp) file. Edit: Just saw your answer which explains this in detail below, and upvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <string>
...
const static std::string QUIT_GAME;
```

Comment: You should never put a `using` statement in a header file.  It irreversibly pollutes the namespace of any file that includes.

Answer (score 2):

Missing the `#include<string>`

and it's `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

try adding at the top:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have typo on `#define`, I reference to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-160) to create dll project, and correct is wrting followiung in header file:

```
#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

but I have typo lose some character and different in `#else #define`:

```
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MATHLIARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
```

after fixing both to the same works.